# Joining data without creating duplicate metric rows from the first table, (second table contains more rows but not metrics)

Tags: postgresql

I have the following two tables that I would like to join for a comprehensive digital marketing report without creating duplicates in regards to metrics. The idea is to take competitor adverts and join them with my existing marketing data which is as follows;

```
 Campaign|Impressions | Clicks | Conversions | CPC |Key                             
---------+------------+--------+-------------+-----+----
  USA-SIM|53432       |  5001  |            5| 2$  |Hgdy24
  DE-SIM |5389        |  4672  |            3| 4$  |dhfg12
```

The competitor data is as follows;

```
     Key | Ad Copie   |
---------+------------+
  Hgdy24 |Click here! |
  Hgdy24 |Free Trial! |
  Hgdy24 |Sign Up now |
  dhfg12 |Check it out|
  dhfg12 |World known |
  dhfg12 |Sign up     |
```

Using conventional join queries produces the following unusable result

```
 Campaign|Impressions | Clicks | Conversions | CPC |Key   |Ad Copie                    
---------+------------+--------+-------------+-----+------+---------
  USA-SIM|53432       |  5001  |            5| 2$  |Hgdy24|Click here!
  USA-SIM|53432       |  5001  |            5| 2$  |Hgdy24|Free Trial!
  USA-SIM|53432       |  5001  |            5| 2$  |Hgdy24|Sign Up now 
  DE-SIM |5389        |  4672  |            3| 4$  |dhfg12|Check it out
  DE-SIM |5389        |  4672  |            3| 4$  |dhfg12|World known
  DE-SIM |5389        |  4672  |            3| 4$  |dhfg12|Sign up
```

Here is the desired output

```
 Campaign|Impressions | Clicks | Conversions | CPC |Key   |Ad Copie                    
---------+------------+--------+-------------+-----+------+---------
  USA-SIM|53432       |  5001  |            5| 2$  |Hgdy24|Click here!
  USA-SIM|            |        |             |     |Hgdy24|Free Trial!
  USA-SIM|            |        |             |     |Hgdy24|Sign Up now 
  DE-SIM |5389        |  4672  |            3| 4$  |dhfg12|Check it out
  DE-SIM |            |        |             |     |dhfg12|World known
  DE-SIM |            |        |             |     |dhfg12|Sign up
```

Or as an alternative that would also work would be

```
 Campaign|Impressions | Clicks | Conversions | CPC |Key   |Ad Copie                    
---------+------------+--------+-------------+-----+------+---------
  USA-SIM|53432       |  5001  |            5| 2$  |Hgdy24|
  USA-SIM|            |        |             |     |Hgdy24|Click here!
  USA-SIM|            |        |             |     |Hgdy24|Free Trial!
  USA-SIM|            |        |             |     |Hgdy24|Sign Up now 
  DE-SIM |5389        |  4672  |            3| 4$  |dhfg12|
  DE-SIM |            |        |             |     |dhfg12|Check it out
  DE-SIM |            |        |             |     |dhfg12|World known
  DE-SIM |            |        |             |     |dhfg12|Sign up
```

I have yet to find a work around that does not produce the extra metrics as a result.

MOST RECENT RESULT

```
 campaing | impressions | clicks | conversions | cpc |  key   |   ad_copie
----------+-------------+--------+-------------+-----+--------+------------
 USA-SIM  |       53432 |   5001 |           5 | 2$  |        |
 USA-SIM  |             |        |             |     | Hgdy24 | Click here!
 USA-SIM  |             |        |             |     | Hgdy24 | Free Trial!
 USA-SIM  |             |        |             |     | Hgdy24 | Sign Up now
 DE-SIM   |        5389 |   4672 |           3 | 4$  |        |
 DE-SIM   |             |        |             |     | dhfg12 | Check it out
 DE-SIM   |             |        |             |     | dhfg12 | World known
 DE-SIM   |             |        |             |     | dhfg12 | Sign up
```

Comment: This is a display formatting issue that is better solved in the application, not in SQL (although it _could_ be done in SQL)

Comment: How would one do it?

Comment: Would it be acceptable to have one row per `key`, but have the `ad_copie` column contain an array of strings? You could select `array_agg(ad_copie)`, and `group by key`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function [lag()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-window.html) to check what `key` was in previous row and either display metrics or null them.

```
select campaing,
       case when prev_key is null or prev_key != key then impressions end as impressions,
       case when prev_key is null or prev_key != key then clicks end as clicks,
       case when prev_key is null or prev_key != key then conversions end as conversions,
       case when prev_key is null or prev_key != key then cpc end as cpc,
       key, ad_copie
  from (
    select campaing, lag(key) over () AS prev_key, impressions, clicks, conversions, cpc, key, ad_copie
    from ad1
    join comp1 using(key)
    order by campaing desc, key
  ) sub;
```

result:

```
 campaing | impressions | clicks | conversions | cpc |  key   |   ad_copie
----------+-------------+--------+-------------+-----+--------+--------------
 USA-SIM  |       53432 |   5001 |           5 | 2$  | Hgdy24 | Click here!
 USA-SIM  |             |        |             |     | Hgdy24 | Free Trial!
 USA-SIM  |             |        |             |     | Hgdy24 | Sign Up now
 DE-SIM   |        5389 |   4672 |           3 | 4$  | dhfg12 | Check it out
 DE-SIM   |             |        |             |     | dhfg12 | World known
 DE-SIM   |             |        |             |     | dhfg12 | Sign up
(6 wierszy)
```

EDIT: You might need to tinker with what columns you compare before you NULL metrics and possibly by what columns you will order data. If key is unique for campaing then I suppose this will suffice.

Comment: Hello Lukasz,  I am having a little bit of trouble formulating this logic, perhaps you could do me a favor and take a look?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46396079/ambiguous-column-within-a-lag-function-query

Comment: I think that Glenn gave you good tip over there - you should create aliases for both tables and prefix all columns with appropriate alias.